# Flatten multiple rows to one row with row values as list in single field python

Tags: pandas, group-by, flatten

I have patients with multiple diagnoses Dx and descriptions DxDesc visiting on a particular date. I would like to flatten this data to *one row per ID and date*, with the diagnostic codes and descriptions joined into one field *each*.

Have:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5, 1, 1],
        'Date':['8/18/2022', '8/18/2022', '8/18/2022', '8/18/2022', '8/18/2022', '8/18/2022', '8/18/2022', '8/18/2022',
               '8/18/2022', '8/18/2022', '8/19/2022', '8/19/2022'],
        'Dx':['J45.1', 'D64.0', '401.9', 'J45.0', 'J45.1', 'D64.0', '401.9', 'J45.0', 'X94', 'Z17', 'J45.1', 'NX87.0'],
        'DxDesc' : ['Asthma', 'Anemia', 'Asthma other', 'Asthma', 'Hypertension', 'Other disease', 'Other disease 2', 
                    'Asthma other', 'Something', 'Something else', 'Asthma', 'Asthma exacerbation']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Want:

ID | Date | DxCodes | DxDescs

1 | 8/18/2022 | 'J45.1', 'D64.0', '401.9' | 'Asthma', 'Anemia', 'Asthma other'

1 | 8/19/2022 | 'J45.1', 'NX87.0' | 'Asthma, 'Asthma exacerbation'

etc.

Answer (score 1):

groupby with aggregate

```
df.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).agg(','.join)
```

```
    ID  Date        Dx                  DxDesc
0   1   8/18/2022   J45.1,D64.0,401.9   Asthma,Anemia,Asthma other
1   1   8/19/2022   J45.1,NX87.0        Asthma,Asthma exacerbation
2   2   8/18/2022   J45.0,J45.1         Asthma,Hypertension
3   3   8/18/2022   D64.0               Other disease
4   4   8/18/2022   401.9,J45.0,X94     Other disease 2,Asthma other,Something
5   5   8/18/2022   Z17                 Something else
```

Comment: @SandraT if you want a list instead of comma separated string, replace `','.join` with a `list`

Comment: Dang that was easier than I thought. Thanks!